# How to play only one sound at a time?

Tags: android

I have two ImageViews with different sounds which plays sound when clicked on one of them. When click on the first ImageView I want the sound to play and before the first ImageView finish playing the sound, if the second ImageView is click, I want to restrict the second ImageView to play a sound because the first ImageView is still playing the sound. In fact, I want to restrict a sound to play when another sound is playing. But, I didn't get the desired result.

```
public class Transportation extends AppCompatActivity {

        private MediaPlayer sound,sound1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.transportation);


            sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vatunabus);
            final ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vatunabussound);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                        sound.stop();
                        sound.release();
                    }
                    else if(sound.isPlaying()){
                        sound.pause();
                        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                    }
                    else {
                        sound.start();
                        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pauseicon);
                    }
                }
            });
            sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                }
            });


            sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.varowlsanabus);
            final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.firstbussound);
            imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(sound.isPlaying()){
                        sound1.stop();
                        sound1.release();
                    }
                    else if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                        sound1.pause();
                        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                    }
                    else {
                        sound1.start();
                        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pauseicon);
                    }

                }
            });
            sound1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, let's create a boolean value to tell us if a sound is currently playing.

```
private MediaPlayer sound,sound1;
private boolean soundPlaying = false; //new boolean variable
```

Next, before playing a sound, we'll check to make sure it's still false:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Add a check that exits the function if a sound is playing
    //Add this check in both onClick methods
    if(soundPlaying){
      return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, after `sound.start()` and `sound1.start()`, let's set the boolean to true:

```
 soundPlaying = true;
```

Finally, in both instances of the onCompletion methods, let's reset the boolean to false:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
   soundPlaying = false;
   ...
}
```

**The final code will look like this:**

```
public class Transportation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer sound,sound1;
    private boolean soundPlaying = false; //new boolean variable

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.transportation);


        sound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vatunabus);
        final ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vatunabussound);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //Add a check that exits the function if a sound is playing
            if(soundPlaying){
              return;
            }
                if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                    sound.stop();
                    sound.release();
                }
                else if(sound.isPlaying()){
                    sound.pause();
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                }
                else {
                    sound.start();
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pauseicon);
                }
            }
        });
        sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                soundPlaying = false;
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
            }
        });


        sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.varowlsanabus);
        final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.firstbussound);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Add a check that exits the function if a sound is playing
                if(soundPlaying){
                  return;
                }
                if(sound.isPlaying()){
                    sound1.stop();
                    sound1.release();
                }
                else if(sound1.isPlaying()){
                    sound1.pause();
                    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
                }
                else {
                    sound1.start();
                    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pauseicon);
                }

            }
        });
        sound1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                soundPlaying = false;
                imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.playicon);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I hope this helps. Couldn't try it in live code though, so let me know how it goes.